# Any way to quickly farm Gladio's Skill?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

My only trophy left is Gladio's Survival at level 10.

Is there a way to quick farm it? Running from one end of the map to the other doesn't seem to work much.

- Any meals can boost Skill XP rate?
- Does riding on Chocobo count?
- Is there some ways to earn a multiplier of XP? Like do running around in dungeons count for more than the overworld?

I know I could just rubber band it, but it kinda removes a part of the acheivement IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to expedite the process of leveling your Survival skill to 10 is to rubber band the controller. Even then, the only reason it is seems "faster" is that you're not spending your own time doing it. It still takes quite a long time. After spending roughly 10+ real hours of walking from city to city to do side quests in the absolute most inefficient way and only reaching rank 6, I ended up rubber banding my controller as well. To get from 6 to 10 took me the entire night as well as some of the following work day.

Distance traveled while riding chocobos will not count towards your Survival skill; only distance covered on foot will. There is no way to shorten the (ridiculous) distance you need to cover for this skill.